# Does Silverlight Support sqlce or Ms Access DB

Tags: database, silverlight-4.0

Does Silverlight support sqlce or MS Access Databe.?

My requirement is my application is OutofBrowser so I need to CRUD Trasaction throught this
so how I can use this.

I had try With Isolation storage database, but I phase the issue with Inserting data and reading data(At the first time I am able to Create DB and Table and also Insert the data, but the second time I phase the issue of inserting means append and also it will create a diffrent different file so reading problem),

so I am very confuge about this, I had also try the Domain Entity Framwork and Domain Service RIA, but it also not support in outofborwser.

What is the actual solution for this.?

Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No SQLCE is not implemented for the Silverlight platform.